# Angular 4: TypeError: this.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

I run out of ideas.. I saw this question got asked many times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690152/javascript-type-error-this-function-is-not-a-function) and many more, but I could not find a way to solve my issue. So as I understood, the problem is `this` it does not refer to the correct context. How do I use an arrow function to capture `this` from the declaration site?

```
drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {
    // more code than displayed here
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch, x, y, w, h);
}
```

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    for (const file of event.target.files) {
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e: FileReaderEvent) {
                const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                const img = new Image;

                img.onload = draw;

                function draw() {
                    this.drawImageProp(ctx, this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0.5, 0.5);
                }

                img.src = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try replacing the functions with arrow functions? For example: `function(e: FileReaderEvent) {...}` would become `(e: FileReaderEvent) => {...}`, and `function draw() {...}` would become `() => {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure:

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    const self = this;
    for (const file of event.target.files) {
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e: FileReaderEvent) {
                const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                const img = new Image;

                img.onload = draw;

                function draw() {
                    self.drawImageProp(ctx, img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0.5, 0.5);
                }

                img.src = e.target.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}
```